# Is there a way to find out how much space in isolated storage you app is using on WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I want to know how many kilobytes/megabytes of isolated storage my app is using on Windows Phone 7. Is there a simple way to find this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
long usedBytes = isf.Quota - isf.AvailableFreeSpace;
```

Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=VS.96).aspx

Comment: The isf.Quota is returning a massively huge number; must larger than the device, which which after subtracting isf.AvailableFreeSpace still results in a number much larger than the device actually has.

Comment: @JohnEgbert you are correct (sorry!). Microsoft's documentation is misleading. I found elsewhere that the AvailableFreeSpace is for the entire device (since your app can use all the space available should you desire) and Quotas aren't actually used (which is why Quota=DefaultQuota and should be ignored). Unfortunately, this means there isn't a simple way to determine your app's usage.  Your best bet would be to iterate over the files and use their stream length as a way to estimate your usage.